# Django & Pyrebase: How do I know if my email is verified or not in firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I am building a web app using Django as the framework and firebase as the database. I am using the [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) API. The API allows sending the verification email but I didn't find any way to find out if the user has verified their email or not. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the `User` object contains an `emailVerified` property.
check if its True

Comment: It is true for the Firebase documentation but I am trying to access it through pyrebase and I can't find anything on the web that lets me do so.

Comment: If you can access user's object then you should be able to check it

Answer (score 1):

You should first sign in with e-mail and password by calling this function
`auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)` (given in the pyrebase documentation) and store its detail in `user` variable. From `user` variable extract id token and call `auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])` (given in the pyrebase documentation) and store its values in some variable name `user_info`. This `user_info` will have a verified flag which can be use for checking the whether the e-mail is verified or not. I hope this solution helps.